# any continuous function is null homotopic for convex set.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. and suppose $B$ is a convex subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that any continuous map $f: X \rightarrow B$ is null-homotopic.

---

My strategy is following the defintion of null-homotopic which is homotopic to constant function $c$.

To prove this find homotopoy $H$ satisfying
\begin{align}
H(t,0) = f(t) \in B \qquad  H(t,1) = c   \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
 define $H$ as 
\begin{align}
  H(t,s) = (1-s) f(t) + s c\in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
which is continuous  and satisfies 
\begin{align}
  H(t,0) = f(t), \qquad H(t,1) = c
\end{align}

---

Is this valid approach? I feel uncomfortable since in the above process i never used the concept of "convex" explicitly.

Comment: Presumably $A$ should be $B$, and $c$ should be chosen to be some particular point in $B$?

Comment: @EricWofsey, you are right. in the above equation $A \rightarrow B$. I correct it. From the definition of null-homotopic which is homotopic to constant function, i chose $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: maybe i am wrong $c \in B$ as a constant function in $B$. But i am still unsatisfactory since i have no use of definition of convex set in the process

Comment: Could you please explain why H is continuous? I am a beginner in homotopy and I have difficulty in showing that. I know that separate continuity does not imply joint continuity, so why is H here continuous in this case?

Comment: I think I have found the answer: just consider the composite of the projection map and H.

Comment: @OscarLiu, Yes from the fact of composition of continuous function is also continuous and linear combination of continuous function is also continuous we can easily show the function like $H$ is continuous.

Comment: When we are talking about linear combinations, are we concerning about normed spaces? So the conclusion can be generalized to the case of (the image is) a convex set in a normed space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct.  The place you use convexity is in knowing that $H(t,s)\in B$ for all $(t,s)$ (remember, you need $H$ to be a map $X\times[0,1]\to B$, not just a map to $\mathbb{R}^n$!).  Since $f(t)\in B$ and $c\in B$, $(1-s)f(t)+sc\in B$ by convexity.  You probably want to mention this explicitly when writing up your solution, both to justify the fact that $H(t,s)\in B$ and to show your reader where you are using convexity.